# Javascript not working after a click on a link in Materialize CSS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, materialize

I am doing `ReactJS` using `MaterializeCSS` for my `UI` and
I have a script in `JS` that looks like one below for `MaterializeCSS` so that I could use modal class.

```
$(document).ready( 
  function () { initializeMaterialize() }
); 

function getUUID() 
{ 
   return (Math.random().toString(36).substring(2)+(new 
   Date()).getTime().toString(36));
}

function initializeMaterialize() {
 $('.modal').modal(); 
 $('select').material_select(); 
 $('select[required]').css({display: 'inline',height: 0,padding: 0,width: 0});
 }
```

In my main **index.html** I called the following as per suggestion from Materialize website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/readable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I was able to use modal and all for Materialize CSS with no problem until I clicked a link from below:

```
        <div className="row">
            <div className="row readable-list-card z-depth-4">
                <div className="float-date">{postDate}</div><br/>
                {/* Title here */}
                <div className="row">
                    {/* Once I click the below link */}
                    <a href={url} onClick={this.handleFetchComments}>
                        <div name="title" ref="myTitle" className="card-title truncate"><strong>Title : </strong>{post.title}</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                {/* Author */}
                <div className="row">
                    <div>By : {post.author}</div>
                </div>
                {/* Vote, Comments, Edit, Delete */}
                <div className="row readable-list-card-bar col s12">
                    <div className="col s6">
                        <div className="chip"><strong className="bold">Vote : </strong><span className="chip-color">{post.voteScore}</span></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <div className="chip"><strong className="bold">Comment : </strong><span className="chip-color">{post.commentCount}</span></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s4">
                        <a className="tooltip2" href="" onClick={this.handleVotePost}><span className="tooltiptext">Vote up</span><i className="material-icons" id="upVote">thumb_up</i></a><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                        <a className="tooltip2" href="" onClick={this.handleVotePost}><span className="tooltiptext">Vote down</span><i className="material-icons" id="downVote">thumb_down</i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s2">
                        <a className="tooltip2 modal-trigger" href="#edit-post" onClick={this.handlePassPost}><span className="tooltiptext">Edit post</span><i className="material-icons">edit</i></a>
                        <a className="tooltip2" href="" onClick={this.handleDeletePost}><span className="tooltiptext">Delete post</span><i className="material-icons">delete</i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div><input type="text" name="postid" style={{display:'none'}} ref={input => this.postid = input} value={post.id}/></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And then click `Home` my `JavaScript` that I declared earlier is no longer accessible.

What could have gone wrong?

I tried to declare my JS on my component using [`Helmet`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) still to no avail.

```
    <Helmet>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/readable.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
     </Helmet>
```